# Extract base url from full url

Tags: android

Any quick way to extract base url from full url? for e.g., if i have http://test.example.com/abcd/test.html - i want only http://test.example.com.

I can always do string parsing - but wanted to know if there is something in Uri where I can get it directly.

Comment: What you are describing is **not** a base url. A base URL is the one specified in [HTML <base> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) which serves as a default target for all **relative** links on a page.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What about:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

try
{
  URL url = new URL("http://test.example.com/abcd/test.html");
  String baseUrl = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost();
}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: works fine, but throws java.net.MalformedURLException, I suggest you use regexp

Comment: Well, garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Thanks gnuf and Ondrej for your answers and comments.

Comment: @gnuf Your method works for base URLs that happen to end on the hostname, but will fail for pages that have an additional path appended.

Comment: this is not taking in consideration the port

Answer (score 6):

[java.net.URL](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL) doc can help you to figure out how to "Extract base url from full url"

**Preliminary note:**

One should pay attention to this **important note** from the [URL javadoc page](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html):

"Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances. The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI, and to convert between these two classes using [toURI()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) and [URI.toURL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html#toURL())."

**Self Explanatory Unit tests:**

Here are 2 simlple unit tests to illustrate the 'base Url' concept

```
package com.elementique.web;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UrlTest {

    @Test
    public void baseUrlAuthority() throws Exception {
        URL url = URI.create("http://username:password@host1:8080/directory/file?query#ref").toURL();

        assertEquals("http", url.getProtocol()); // protocol is also known as 'scheme'
        assertEquals("username:password@host1:8080", url.getAuthority());

        String baseUrlAuthority= url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority();
        assert (url.toString().startsWith(baseUrlAuthority));
    }

    @Test
    public void baseUrlHostAndDefaultPort() throws Exception {
        URL url = URI.create("http://host2/a/b/c").toURL();

        assertEquals(-1, url.getPort()); // -1 as port is not defined in this case

        String baseUrlHostAndDefaultPort= url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost();
        assert (url.toString().startsWith(baseUrlHostAndDefaultPort));
    }
}
```

**Extracting base URL:**

So, "extracting base Url from full url" can be done like this:

```
return url.getProtocol()+"://"+url.getAuthority()+"/"
```

Or this, if you do NOT want the username/password part

```
if(url.getPort() == -1){ // port is not
    return url.getProtocol()+"://"+url.getHost()+"/";
} else {
    return url.getProtocol()+"://"+url.getHost()+":"+url.getPort()+"/";
}
```

**Implementation:**

Here is an implementation that does that (based on getAuthority() ):

```
public static String getBaseUrl(String urlString)
{

    if(urlString == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        URL url = URI.create(urlString).toURL();
        return url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + "/";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note:
Remove the trailing "/" is you don't want it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the Android URI class that gives you the base URL directly-  As gnuf suggests, you'd have to construct it as the protocol + getHost().

The string parsing way might be easier and let you avoid stuffing everything in a try/catch block.  Just take a substring of the URL, everything from the beginning of the string to the third "/" symbol.

Comment: Sure. But you have to be careful about URLs that don't have a path part and don't include the optional third `/` (permitted by RFC 1738, Sec 3.3). I guess it comes down to whether you are trusting the incoming URL to be valid.