# WebView: How to find the base URL of the current page?

Tags: android, html, webview

WebView has [getUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29) and it has [loadDataWithBaseUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) but I can't find a method that returns the base URL (note: "base URL" is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492944/extract-base-url-from-full-url/4493009#comment-8561124) the same as server/host path).

Is there a way to find the base URL of the current web page, even for pages that don't use the  tag, but do use relative URLs in links contained in the page?

Note the complexity of the problem:

- [getUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29) isn't always the base URL.
- [Server/host path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492944/extract-base-url-from-full-url/4493009#4493009) isn't always the base URL.
- Web pages don't always contain the [`<base>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag.

This may explain why there isn't a single `WebView` method to provide the base URL...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
URL url = new URL(mWebView.getUrl());
```

With the `URL` object, you can do get things like path, host, etc. Check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) for more info.

Comment: `getUrl()` isn't always the base URL. Server/host path isn't always the base URL. Web pages don't always contain the `<base>` tag. The problem is more complicated than this...

Comment: You could [extract the web source](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/), then parse out the `<base>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem, but randomly found a solution. In method `loadDataWithBaseURL` set the `historyUrl` to your `baseUrl`. Now when you requesting `webView.getUrl()` it always returns your `baseUrl`.